# How to delete a forge bucket from Autodesk forge

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am successfully creating Bucket and uploadFile successfully using sample.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions

I added the delete function
But when I delete the bucket I get an error.

[image: ForgeTree Image]

[image: Error Image]

----oss.js---

```
router.post('/buckets', async (req, res, next) => {
    let payload = new PostBucketsPayload();
    payload.bucketKey = config.credentials.client_id.toLowerCase() + '-' + req.body.bucketKey;
    payload.policyKey = 'transient'; // expires in 24h


    try {
        // Create a bucket using [BucketsApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/BucketsApi.md#createBucket).
        //Bucket createBucket(postBuckets, opts, oauth2client, credentials)
        await new BucketsApi().createBucket(payload, {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
        res.status(200).end();
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
});


router.delete('/buckets/delete', async (req, res, next) => {

    const encoded_bucketKey = encodeURI(req.bucketKeyID);

     
    try {
        // Delete a bucket using 
        await new BucketsApi().deleteBucket(encoded_bucketKey,  req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
        res.status(200).end();
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

-----------ForgeTree.js -------

```
function createNewBucket() {
  var bucketKey = $('#newBucketKey').val();
  var policyKey = $('#newBucketPolicyKey').val();
 

  jQuery.post({

    url: '/api/forge/oss/buckets',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'bucketKey': bucketKey, 'policyKey': policyKey }),
    success: function (res) {
      $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).refresh();
      $('#createBucketModal').modal('toggle');
    },
    error: function (err) {
      if (err.status == 409)
        alert('Bucket already exists - 409: Duplicated')
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}

function deleteBucket() {

  var node = $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[0];

  switch (node.type) {
    case 'bucket':
      
        jQuery.ajax({

          url: '/api/forge/oss/buckets/delete',
          type:'delete',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify({ 'bucketKey': node.text , 'bucketKeyID' : node.id}),
          success: function (res) {
            $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).refresh();

          },
          error: function (err) {
            
             alert('Bucket delete error:')
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
    break;

  
  }

  console.log("Delete Bucket=%j", node)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the config.js in the sample, it doesn't include bucket:delete scope when acquiring the token by default. Have you added the scope in your code?

Also inside delete route,

```
const encoded_bucketKey = encodeURI(req.bucketKeyID);
```

should be

```
const encoded_bucketKey = encodeURI(req.body.bucketKeyID);
```

Otherwise, you'll have undefined as encoded_bucketKey.

Comment: thank you.

i changed the source code.
But I get the same error.

---config.js------

 internal: ['bucket:create', 'bucket:read', 'bucket:delete', 'data:read', 'data:create', 'data:write'],

Comment: I checked again.
const encoded_bucketKey = encodeURI(req.bucketKeyID);
should be 
const encoded_bucketKey = encodeURI(req.body.bucketKeyID);

Comment: I succeeded with your help.
thank you so much